# Possible Injection to PHP PDO

Tags: php, attacks, exploit

Expert says that PDO is one of secure scripting from mysql injection. I have read the manual about it and do some little research. And here, I'm trying to get ID value from URL paramater, as in:

```
<?php
include("pdo_con.php");

if (isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id=$_GET['id'];
    $id=strip_tags($id);
    }
    $sth = $mydb->prepare("SELECT * FROM ra_articlez WHERE id=:id");
    $sth->execute(array(':id' => $id ));
    $result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if ($result>0){
        $updatedb = $mydb->prepare("UPDATE ra_articlez SET count=count+1 WHERE id=:id");
        $updatedb->bindParam(':id', $id);
        $updatedb->execute();
        }
?>
```

from the codes above, link with that parameter is like this:

```
www. website . com/article.php?id=1
```

Is it already secure? Do I have to add an attribute, say, strip_tags, html entities? or to declare `intval` before the `ID` in `..... WHERE id ......`?, 
Any help would be very so great! Thanks.

Comment: why voting me down without reason? reason is more useful, right?

Comment: From http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php: "The parameters to prepared statements don't need to be quoted; the driver automatically handles this. If an application exclusively uses prepared statements, the developer can be sure that no SQL injection will occur...". You got downvoted because you should have read the manual before posting this question.

Comment: :D , thanks for reply. I just think as my security theory: "no perfect protection made by human", so prevention must be the first thing to consider before everything goes away. Thief is cleverer then "padlock".

I have read the manual and do some little research if it is possible and as we know that we wish our site is very very secure from attacks.

What about using SSL plus PDO scripting, I think that's one of efforts, right? thanks so much anyway!

Comment: Jean - does this question cover off what you are asking: http://stackoverflow.com/q/134099/529337

Comment: I'm just back from work. sorry late to reply. yes, that's logic. I didn't find the link unfortunately. thanks @RoryAlsop. this little link is useful for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it already secure?

Yes, you did use prepared statements correctly, and with all we know right now, that should be secure (assuming you don't use some [odd multibyte character set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134099/are-pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection/12202218#12202218)). If security issues in PDO are found in the future, you will probably hear about it, and if you regularly update your software, it should be fixed in reasonable time.

> Do I have to add an attribute, say, strip_tags, html entities?

You don't have to, and you shouldn't either. You shouldn't change data when inserting it in the database, that will just lead to problems later on.

`strip_tags` and `htmlentities` are used to prevent XSS (although [you shouldn't use `strip_tags`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605629/prevent-xss-with-strip-tags)), which is an attack that happens when printing data to the user, not when inserting it into the database. And that is where you should defend against it (this leads to cleaner data, cleaner code, and better security).

> or to declare intval before the ID

You can use something like `is_numeric($input)` or something like `(int) $input == $input`. It's not a bad idea from a UX point of view (you can report something like `Only integers are acceptable`, and it's not bad as defense in depth (although it's not needed either).

> What about using SSL plus PDO scripting?

SSL is something completely different. It will not protect your server from attacks at all, but will protect your users (keep in mind that you are probably a user as well) against man in the middle attacks (which can eg be used to steal their passwords or read private data). If you have sensitive data and/or a login form it might be a good idea to use SSL/TLS.

What would grant you additional security against attacks would be an application layer firewall such as mod_security, which basically checks all input against a couple of regexes to find and prevent attacks (you shouldn't rely on this though, it's just an additional layer of security).

Comment: thanks so much @Tim, that's so clear. I admit I still used the attributes to make sure that everything is fine before. I really appreciate. thnks again.